# What's the difference between maven project and dynamic web project?

Tags: eclipse, maven

They look very similar to each other , I wonder why people divide it.
They both can have dependency injection
Is anyone knows the major difference?

Comment: The major difference is that dynamic web projects work with what you have on your system, maven projects know how to download missing bits from the internet.